# Как рисовать кастомные фигуры в WinForms / WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, графика

Делаю лабораторную работу по полиморфизму. Даны классы фигур: Фигура, Круг, Сегмент, Сектор, Дуга, Шар, Шаровой слой. Потом идут требования, это не интересно. Интересно то, что мне нужно эти фигуры рисовать либо в консоли, что является идиотизмом, либо в WinForms (WPF). И вот я плавно подобрался к сути вопроса: как отрисовать кастомные классы фигур со своими полями, методами, свойствами? Есть ли конкретный способ решения этой задачи? Спасибо

Comment: Есть библиотека `System.Drawing`, ее можно хоть из консоли, хоть из winforms использовать. Берете битмап и рисуете на нем что требуется. Чтобы показать битмап в форме, есть в винформах контрол `PictureBox`. Для консоли, битмап можно записать например в жпег файл.

Answer (score 2):

В коде использовал класс `System.Drawing.Graphics`. Про него почитать можно вот [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawellipse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Начнем с базового класса. Обозначим базовый для всех как `Shape`:

```
internal abstract class Shape
{
    protected Shape(Color borderColor, int borderWidth)
    {
        BorderColor = borderColor;
        BorderWidth = borderWidth;
    }

    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    public Color BorderColor { get; protected set; }
    public int BorderWidth { get; protected set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public abstract void Draw(Graphics graphics);
}
```

От него создадим два класса, круг и квадрат. Я сделал только два самых простых, но я думаю не проблема нарисовать дугу или что-нибудь посложнее, что у вас по заданию

```
internal class Square : Shape
{
    public Square(int size, Color borderColor, int borderWidth) : base(borderColor, borderWidth)
    {
        Size = size;
        Name = "Квадрат";
    }

    public int Size { get; set; }

    public override void Draw(Graphics graphics)
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen(BorderColor, BorderWidth);
        graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Size, this.Size));
    }
}
```

```
internal class Circle : Shape
{
    public Circle(int radius, Color borderColor, int borderWidth) : base(borderColor, borderWidth)
    {
        R = radius;
        Name = "Круг";
    }

    public int R { get; set; }

    public override void Draw(Graphics graphics)
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen(BorderColor, BorderWidth);
        graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.R, this.R));
    }
}
```

Теперь можно приходить к окну. Три элемента: `PictureBox`, `ComboBox` и `Button`. В `ComboBox` выбираем нужный нам элемент, а кнопкой рисуем. Выводим в `PictureBox`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внутри класса окна:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Текущий элемент в ComboBox
    private Shape _currentShape;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var circle = new Circle(150, Color.Black, 2);
        var square = new Square(150, Color.Black, 2);
        comboBox1.Items.Add(circle);
        comboBox1.Items.Add(square);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Чистим изображение, иначе будут накладываться друг на друга
        pictureBox1.Image = null;
        pictureBox1.Update();
        
        //Рисуем
        _currentShape = (Shape)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
        _currentShape.Draw(pictureBox1.CreateGraphics());
    }
}
```